# How to write mysql connection string in app.config in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  
<configuration>  
<Connectionstring>  
<add key="questionpaper" value="server=localhost;database=Question_info;  
 UID=root;password=SATISH;"/>  
</Connectionstring>    
<startup>   
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />   
</startup>     
</configuration>
```

this is my app.config but unable to connect to MySql server
   so please tell me how to deal with this problem
   How to write mysql connection string in app.config in c#

Comment: Ŝee if [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45321-grabbing-connectionstring-from-appconfig/) helps.

Comment: It would help if you told us how it doesn't work. In the mean time checkout connectionstrings.com.

Comment: @Salem i tried your code but it gives error Authentication to host "for user" using method mysql_native_password failed with message : access denied for user '@bhaurao' (using password:NO)

Comment: So your are not connecting to localhost? If that is the case, you need to make MySQL accept remote connections.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pluralize the connectionStrings tag.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name"ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=databaseName;Intergated Security=SSPI;Application Name=My.Application.Name" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The add key/value tag is also the format to use for appSettings, not connectionStrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="questionpaper" connectionString="SERVER=localhost; DATABASE=Question_info; UID=root; PASSWORD=SATISH" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```